# Hazelcast/Coherence Grid Computing EntryProcessor with data for each key

Tags: hazelcast, oracle-coherence, grid-computing

I want to use hazelcast or coherence EntryProcessor to process some logic in parallel execution on different nodes where the keys are stored in a cache. I see i can use something like sendToEachKey(EntryProcessor process).

My problem comes when i need to send also with the logic a piece of data to process too that belongs to another system and i receive it(in a http request for example).

Sure i can do something like sendToEachKey(EntryProcessor(data) process). But if the data it's diferent to each key and i want to send to a specific key only his data to process, how can i do that? Why i want to do that is because the data is too big and I have network overload.

Sure that if I open a thread pool to send each data to each key is possible but it is inefficient because of the huge requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Hazelcast you could retrieve all values and send each key it's own `EntryProcessor`, however this will create a lot of overhead.

The other option would be to use a combination of `EntryProcessor` and our distributed `ExecutorService`.

You send a `Runnable` to an ExecutorService. Inside the `Runnable` you retrieve the local keyset, retrieve all the external values (all that already local to the node) and than you emit one `EntryProcessor` per local key. Since you're already local to the node, there's no more traffic flying around (apart from the backups, obviously :)). That said you might want to implement a specific `EntryProcessor` that only transmits the changed value but not the full processor itself (to save even more traffic).

Comment: This. I came here to write the same recommendation.`IExecutorService.submitToKeyOwner(Callable/Runnable, key)` can be used for easy solution.

Comment: Thanks! It's what i think could be the best.

Answer (score 1):

In Coherence you could use `PartitionedService` to find association of cache keys to cluster members. Then you could invoke entry processor with data for each member, using `PartitionedFilter` to make sure that data is sent only to that member. Something like this:

```java
// keys in this map are also keys in cache
void processData(Map<String, Data> externalData) { 
    PartitionedService partitionedService = (PartitionedService) cache.getCacheService();
    Map<Member, Map<String, Data>> dataForMembers = splitDataByMembers(partitionedService, externalData);

    for (Entry<Member, Map<String, Data>> dataForMember : dataForMembers.entrySet()) {
        Member member = dataForMember.getKey();
        Map<String, Data> data = dataForMember.getValue();

        PartitionSet partitions = partitionedService.getOwnedPartitions(member);
        PartitionedFilter filter = new PartitionedFilter<>(Filters.always(), partitions);
        EntryProcessor processor = new MyEntryProcessor(data);
        cache.async().invokeAll(filter, processor);
    }
}

Map<Member, Map<String, Data>> splitDataByMembers(
        PartitionedService partitionedService,
        Map<String, Data> externalData) {
    Map<Member, Map<String, Data>> dataForMembers = new HashMap<>();

    for (Object member : partitionedService.getInfo().getServiceMembers()) {
        dataForMembers.put((Member) member, new HashMap<>());
    }
    for (Entry<String, Data> dataForKey : externalData.entrySet()) {
        Member member = partitionedService.getKeyOwner(dataForKey.getKey());
        dataForMembers.get(member).put(dataForKey.getKey(), dataForKey.getValue());
    }
    return dataForMembers;
}
```

This way there will be only one entry processor invocation for each member in cluster and each member will get only data it is interested in.

I used `String` as a cache key and arbitrary `Data` type for data associated with this key, but you could of course use any other types (and you don't have to model external data as a map at all).

Answer (score 0):

In Hazelcast you would be doing `executeOnKeys(keys, new EntryProcessor(data))` and this is too much as the data is too big.

Why not

```java
executeOnKey(key1, new EntryProcessor(data1));
executeOnKey(key2, new EntryProcessor(data2));
executeOnKey(key3, new EntryProcessor(data3));
```

to send the data subset each key needs ?